# How to format date when using primeng calendar?

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar, primeng

How to get only date,month and year when using Prime NG p-calendar component? i got these value when i do console.log my variable. It showed this value :

> Date {Wed Feb 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)}

So i don't want it that long, i just need 01/02/2017, i don't need the rest. So how can i get date,month and year format? since i already did this :

here is my html :

and here is my component.ts :

```
export class report {

  public date: any;


  constructor() {

  }

  public proses(date) {

    console.log(date);

  }

}
```

Comment: where does `proses` come from? I'm trying to do the same as you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using pure JavaScript Date functions like this:

```
let day = date.getDate();
let month = date.getMonth() + 1; // add 1 because months are indexed from 0
let year = date.getFullYear();

console.log(day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
```

The other way is using the toLocaleDateString() method like this:

```
let newDate = date.toLocaleDateString();
console.log(newDate);
```

Or you can use some library as i.e. moment.js which you can use in the following way:

```
let newDate = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY').toString();
console.log(newDate();
```

Both solutions will console log the same string.

Comment: just for a little memo, to get date is to use date.getDate if date.getDay i will get what day in that date

Comment: @KeVin, you are right, it was like literal error. Sorry for the problem and thanks for the perceptivity. I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I needed this answer and I don't think I found it in the most voted answer. The question is how to get it using the element **p-calendar** from *Prime NG* and we just just have a way to do it with pure JavaScript. I found the simple way to do it as the question asks, so, this is my answer:

```
<p-calendar dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" dataType="string"></p-calendar>
```

You can choose the way the value will be using "dateFormat" and choose the dataType as string to get the value just as it is in the input.

Comment: Its 2023 and you just saved me SO MUCH TIME! Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't work on v2.10 I guess?

Comment: You mean Angular v2.10, right? I can't be sure, It's an old version. But if I'm not mistaken, ngPrime for Angular started for V7, so probabily, it does not even install for this version.

Answer (score 2):

```
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

datePipe.transform(selectedDate, formatInWhichYouWantOutput)
```